# Can't find good info on how to setup a printer server on OSX leopard server edition

Tags: mac-osx, print-server

Can anyone point in the direction of some good resources on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the Snow Leopard Print Server documentation?

http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/resources/documentation.html